# If two Riemannian manifolds are isometric as metric spaces, must they be isometric as Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

In other words, is it possible that distinct Riemannian metrics can induce the same metric space structure on a smooth manifold?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the Meyers-Steenrod Theorem:  If $f:M\to N$ is distance-preserving (i.e., $d_N(f(p),f(q))=d_M(p,q)$ for all $p,q\in M$) and surjective, then $f$ is a Riemannian isometry.  I can't think of a reference off hand, but I believe it's typically an exercise in most texts (I seem to recall it as an exercise in Lee's Riemannian text, but I could be mistaken).